# A keys-only query cost if sorted

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am looking into using Google Datastore for a project of mine. I would like to retrieve all the keys of the entities but I would like it sorted by newest -> oldest:

```
query.select('__key__').order('DateCreated');;

query.run(function(err, entities) {
  var keys = entities.map(function(entity) {
    return entity[datastore.KEY];
  });
});
```

If inside of my entity I have a "Date Created" field can I use this field to sort the results while the query still being considered a "free" operation meaning it will cost me nothing to get the results? Or if I do sort this using my own attribute inside the entity does this then cost me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're still keys-only queries. From the [Pricing and Quota](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing):

> ```
> Small Operations Unlimited Free
> ```
>
> Small operations include calls to allocate Cloud Datastore IDs or
>   keys-only queries.